# Coinbase Pro API for a React client

Tags: reactjs, cors, coinbase-api

I'm trying to develop a React client which should allow the user to rebalance its portfolio.

The problem is that I can't authenticate due to a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cb-access-passphrase is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Maybe this API is not meant to be used from clients?

Comment: If Coinbase has CORS enabled on their API, they must intend to allow clients to query it cross-origin. However, Coinbase's CORS indeed seems to be misconfigured. I'd raise an issue with them.

Comment: I opened a ticket, hopefully when I reveive an answer I'll give you an update